# How can I toggle the Fn (function) key?

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

Is there a way to toggle the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key?  I'd like to be able to toggle it so I don't have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to raise the volume, for example.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on an Asus D550C.

Comment: This could be an option in your bios.

Comment: Should be in your BIOS → config → is usually either „F1-F12 as Primary Function: On“ or something like „HotKey Mode“ (change from enabled to disabled or vice versa)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key does not get detected by the OS but modifies your other keys on a firmware level. That means you can neither retrieve nor control the state of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key from Ubuntu.

---

What you could do instead is to change the keyboard shortcut for increasing/decreasing audio volume to an alternative key combination instead of the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-modified special key.

Open **System Settings → Keyboard** and go to the **Shortcuts** tab. In the list on the left side, select **Sound and Media**.

After clicking on an entry in the list on the right side (in your case you want to edit **Volume up** and **Volume down**), you can press a combination of keys you want to assign to this shortcut. <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels the editing and <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> disables the shortcut.

Comment: Great tip because you can use one hand.

Comment: Brightness up and down?

Comment: It was necessary to select function key behavior in bios for me.

Answer (score 296):

For some computer models, to toggle <kbd>F1</kbd> .. <kbd>F12</kbd> keys use media functions or to be
the "F" keys press <kbd>Fn</kbd> +  <kbd>Esc</kbd> .

Comment: Works with some laptops like Lenovo Thinkpad series.

Comment: Works great on my Lenovo T460 and Dell XPS 15

Comment: Works with Dell Inspirion 5000 series. Thank you Andrey

Comment: Fn + Esc Works like a charm on my DELL Inspiron 15 ~ Thanks!
Not sure what 'media functions' is/means

Comment: it seems not to be working on macbook pro 11,4

Comment: This doesn't work on all laptop brands...

Comment: In the HP Zbook G5 the shortcut is _Fn + Shift_ https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108

Comment: This works on my Dell Latitude. And this should have been the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: doesn't work on Dell XPS 9570 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS :(

Comment: This worked on Dell Vostro series laptop, I was confused what the hell happened doing this reversed the keys back to normal

Comment: Doesn't work on my HP laptop Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Lovely! works on Dell XPS 15, Ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: Worked on my Dell G7 with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Tip of the day! I recently bought a new MSI Prestige that swaps the F keys with volume, keyboard backlight, etc. I'm a developer, so I always need the original F key functionality. I wish I could upvote this answer twice.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on LenovoP50

Comment: Works in 2022 with Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 cheers

Comment: Works on Dell Latitude 7420 with Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks! :)

Comment: Worked for HP Dev One PopOS 22.04 external keyboard, thanks!

Comment: Works on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 (2023)

Comment: Works on Dell Precision 5560 with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Thinkpad escape key even says clearly: "Esc/FnLock", so just do Fn+Esc to switch.

Comment: works well on Dell Precision 3581 and Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 80):

If you have an Apple keyboard and want the function keys to act like <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> by default (disable <kbd>Fn</kbd> default behavior) give the following command in terminal:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior

Comment: Works for a MBP 6,1 (2010 17")

Comment: Worked on HP laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 using an Apple keyboard.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18 Ubuntu desktop w/ Apple keyboard

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu/PopOS 20.04 and doesn't even require reboot

Comment: Work with feker machinist 01, Ubuntu 18.04, no reboot :)

Comment: How can I make this work across reboots?

Comment: @A.Steenbergen you can probably use `sysfsutils` - see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915982/ubuntu-17-04-macbook-pro-tilde-key-fix/915983#915983) for an example (for a different setting - adjust as needed).

Comment: Great, worked on ubuntu 20.04 with Keychron K3 keyboard (Mac mode)

Comment: Thanks! Got a new Vamillo (VA88M) keyboard, using with PopOS, and the fact that media controls were the default action was bugging me.

Comment: works for manjaro system as well

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 21.10 using a Matias keyboard, thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm on latest Gnome! First time I see gnome changing my Fn .. unsure why but thanks

Comment: I have a 3rd party keyboard that claims "apple compatible", using Ubuntu 22 and this also fixed my issue.

Comment: Also worked with my Keychron keyboard.

Answer (score 23):

Press  <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Fn Lock</kbd>. It will toggle between Enable and Disable.

Comment: is "Fn Lock" supposed to be a separate key? If so, where could it be found?

Comment: @foo its your Escape(Esc) key, in the top left corner.

Comment: In that case, this is the same as /u/Andrew's answer --- and it doesn't work on all systems.

Comment: I've just realized that there is a small FnLk written on my Thinkpad X250s Escape button. Easier to find out next time.

Comment: On HP laptops the fn lock key is the left shift key.

Comment: @Marijn `Fn + Left Shift Key` worked on my HP Probook. Thanks Man

Answer (score 16):

My laptop has a <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> key which is useful, except when it's been pressed by accident. Then pressing F5 in Firefox doesn't reload the page; it switches off the touch pad. I now know what it is but it had me totally bamboozled having to reboot or logout to get the touch pad back working.

Comment: With the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 this key is called `F lock` and is located on the top row next to F12. Pressing it toggles a green LED at the bottom of the keyboard with an F below it.  If the LED is off, the function keys don't work.

Answer (score 6):

On HP probook 450, left shift has <kbd>fn lock</kbd>, so <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>leftShift</kbd> locks it.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Num Lock</kbd> to disable it.

Comment: Confirmed for Kloner Bluetooth Keyboard KTB0025.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the BIOS. For Acer laptop I can choose the toggle on <kbd>Fn</kbd> touch in it.

Comment: That was very helpful, i switched from media key to function key at BIOS

Answer (score 1):

In addition to zardosht answer above as I cannot comment yet.

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

To make this work after reboots I followed Zanna's link to add in `sysfutils` [Ubuntu 17.04 Macbook Pro Tilde key Fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915982/ubuntu-17-04-macbook-pro-tilde-key-fix/915983#915983)

Added this in the last line to end of file

`module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode = 2`

save, reboot and should be working.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this saved my day! If someone gets here, this will switch the function keys to the default behaviour, keeping multimedia working with FN key!

Comment: This helped me as well:

I have a mechanical keyboard from a chinese manufacturer  - Hello Gonass which has an fn key. Works fine on windows but the fn keys don't work on Linux.

`echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` makes it work again.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04
From BIOS (if `fn + Esc` is not work)

- Go to the `Bios`
- Navigate to the `Main` tab
- Look for the `Function Key Behaviour` setting and set `Function Key` instead of the `Media Key` option.

Answer (score 0):

On some Keyboard, the <kbd>left shift</kbd> is the <kbd>fn lock</kbd> key. Press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>left shift</kbd> to toggle

Answer (score 0):

On microsoft keyboard with trackpad:

[Fn-Caps]

Answer (score 0):

On Huawei laptops, press `fn` key once. This will toggle the behaviour. On some models, the "disabled" behaviour will be indicated with a LED light on.