# Ubuntu 17.04 Macbook Pro Tilde key Fix

Tags: keyboard, 17.04, macbook-pro

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 on a 2015 Macbook Pro. On the keyboard the Tilde<kbd>~</kbd>/Backtick`</kbd> key is mapped to`<`and`>`. I have found a few fixes for this, but have found no way to make it permanent.

I have found that the command

```
echo 0 > sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout
```

corrects the issue, as does

```
setxkbmap -option apple:badmap
```

My issue is getting either of these commands to run inside of a script at startup/login so that I am not having to manually run it every time I want it fixed. I have tried using `/etc/rc.local` but in Ubuntu 17.04 when trying to enable it with `systemctl` I get no results. I will take anything that will work. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to make changes to `/sys` at boot is to use `sysfsutils`. The package may not be installed by default, so first do:

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

now edit the file `/etc/sysfs.conf`, for example:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysfs.conf
```

and add this line to the end of it, then save, exit, and reboot:

```
module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout = 0
```

This will do the same as your `echo` command.

Comment: @Castor_RG great to hear that :) it's a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Zanna wasn't working for me, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1341387/557926) was.
So in my case I had to create `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` and set its contents to:

```
options hid_apple iso_layout=0
```

I also wanted the F keys to work like regular F1-F12 keys so I also added

```
options hid_apple fnmode=2
```

This worked after rebooting my computer.