# I set /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode to 2 and it gets overwritten to 1 on each reboot

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook

I'm running Ubuntu alone on a Macbook, with no dual boot. I run:

```
echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

both as *root* and with `sudo chmod`, but after restarting it's back to `1`.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu,  edit `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` and put `options hid_apple fnmode=2` This is an answer from this site https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I did that, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

After editing `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` and putting `options hid_apple fnmode=2`, you need to run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot after that.