# Keep keyboard "fn" keys mapping after reboot (pressing only F5 should refresh my browser)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have this mechanical keyboard Varmilo VA88M

https://www.kustompcs.co.uk/peripherals/keyboards/mechanical-keyboards/varmilo-va88m-charcoal-pbt-backlit-mx-brown-switch-tkl-uk-keyboard/

that I have connected to a Thinkpad P43s laptop running ubuntu 20.04.

I would like the function keys to default to "normal" behavior meaning that if I press F5 in a browser it will refresh the page. But right now I need to hold down the `Fn` key and `F5` on the varmilo keyboard to get that behavior.

Based on:

[How can I toggle the Fn (function) key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key)

I have tried to run:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

from a terminal and the it works! But I have to do the above after each reboot of my laptop.

Is there a way to permanently configure the function keys to have "normal" behavior as described above?

Comment: Unless your keyboard can remember it (and that's very keyboard specific), the "standard" way would be to configure it when plugged in using a udev rule.

Comment: Hm could you provide an example