# "fn" key on laptops

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am a windows user looking to make the switch to linux, and I've tried both mint and ubuntu from a usb stick. I think I might make the move to ubuntu, as I love its bold and simple style. But I'm worried about the "fn" keys on my laptop. On my laptop, fn+arrow keys control brightness and volume, and combinations of fn+function keys gives me some shortcuts. Does Ubuntu come with appropriate drivers to retain those keyboard functions?

My laptop is an Acer vx15.

Regards

Comment: Mint is not on-topic here, as it's neither Ubuntu, or flavor of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). This isn't a generic Linux support site (SE *Unix & Linux* is that), however I do know *fn* keys work on the many devices I test Ubuntu and *flavors* on, as I test for that pre-release (I'm involved in QA testing).  You can test yourself though, so why don't you - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  (*which works for Ubuntu flavors too*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu does have the appropriate drivers for that. I know this from my experience. My laptop is from 2010 and all Fn shortcuts are still functioning properly. In case your Ubuntu installation doesn't come with proper drivers  for that, you can manually set those shortcuts.

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key#:~:text=Open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key#:%7E:text=Open) System Settings → Keyboard,to assign to this shortcut.