# Problem with disabling F1 key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, settings

I want to disable the commands associated to my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in particular the <kbd>F1</kbd> command which activates the sleep mode.

In addition, <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys alone are not present in the Keyboard Shortcuts (in the settings). I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200893/how-to-disable-multimedia-keys-entirely-18-04-lts) but I am not able to find the <kbd>F1</kbd> key removal.

In addition, if I try to assign an "empty" command to <kbd>F1</kbd> via Keyboard Shortcuts I notice that the name of <kbd>F1</kbd> is "sleep". In this way <kbd>F1</kbd> is no longer associated to sleep mode but I cannot use it for other programs.

My Ubuntu version is 20.10.

Comment: Fn keys are hardware wired so you will not find a solution for this. There is a key combination to disable Fn. `Fn+Super+Esc` or `Fn Esc`  or `Cntrl Shift T`  and there will be a few more.

Comment: Your BIOS also has an option to disable Fn. Topic about this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key

Comment: @Rinzwind I have also found that pressing Fn+Esc should remove the default behaviour but in my case F1 means sleep mode so it is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BIOS:

Function key behaviour ---> Function key.

while the default setting is Media Key. If, for example, F1 is associated to sleep mode, using function key setting, you have to press Fn + F1 in order to have the sleep mode.

In the BIOS function key behaviour can be found inside a subsection of advanced like other.