# Need to use fn to use the shortcuts on the function keys after upgrading to 23.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 23.04

I was using the lts version before and the action keys were working fine .
But after upgrading to 23.04 i have to now use fn keys to use the action keys like volume control, brightness , media ,etc.

Is there any way to fix this i tried searching in the setting but couldn't find any i'm new to ubuntu and need any help that i can get.

i have tried `gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up`
but it didn't work .

Comment: Any help in the answers here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key

Comment: What hardware are you using? Is this a laptop? Which one? Does it have a fn lock button?

Comment: @terdon i'm currently using HP Pavilion Laptop  14-dv0xxx with core i5 , Xe graphics , it doesn't have a fn lock key

Comment: Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Looks like hp provide instructions to do this from the bios here https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_5878386-5878448-16#:~:text=the%20Startup%20Menu.-,Press%20the%20f10%20key%20to%20open%20the%20BIOS%20Setup%20menu,Disable%20the%20Fn%20Key%20switch.